# how to get specific lenght from txt to array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a text file with about 10000 words, each on a separate line. The program needs to read an integer from the console. Then, the program needs to save  each word in test.txt where the length of the word corresponds to the number input by the user to the array list.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class diplomska {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String besede[] = new String[10000];
        int i = 0;
        System.out.println("Vnesi dožino besede, ki jo iščeš");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System. in );
        int dolzina = in .nextInt();

        try {
            try {
                Scanner vrstica = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
                vrstica.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                String ln = vrstica.next();

                if (i == dolzina)


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check your code first it is not properly intended as there are mistakes in opening and closing curly brackets please make sure while you posting the code must be well intended and specific

Comment: If one of the responses answered your question, please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

the length of a string can be measured with `length()` method of a string.
So `i = ln.length()`

**if your goal is to output the words** :

use `System.out.println(ln);`

**if your goal is to save the words** :

the problem with arrays is, that they arent dynamic in length. Use [Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html). You can add the matching elements with `add(T t)` method. The number u can get with `int size()`method. Deleting the solution can be accomplished via `clear()` method.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
(i==dolzina)
```

to

```
if(ln.length()==dolzina)
```

and after, use   `System.out.println(ln);`

There's no need to save an array of strings since your end goal is to simply print out all strings where the length is provided by user.

Comment: i need to save to array, since later i need used to input lets say P???aa and gets possible results (? meaining any letter)

Comment: In that case, as Terry Storm suggested, you ought to use a list. Lists allow you to add elements in constant time. As long as you don't need to remove elements once added, a list will work well.

Do you need to check for repeats? If so, you might consider a HashMap

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the words list.

```
while (vrstica.hasNext()) {
    String ln = vrstica.next();
    if (ln.length() == dolzina) {
        // save to the array
        besede[i] = ln;
        i++;
    }
}
```

You can also use a `List` instead of an array since its size is dynamic.